# Passing Backbone Fetch/Initialise Variable to the view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

Using Backbone to gather collections from a JSON service, I have using the view initialise to activate the fetch, however I now want to pass the JSON Array back to the view, but I'm unsure how to achieve this...

The following code is what I'm currently using:

```
app.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({

        initialize: function(){


            // Instanciate a new Form collection (which is derrived from the input model)
            var inputs = new app.Form();

            // Perform a GET on the model url to the service
            inputs.fetch({

                success: function() {

                    var questions = inputs.get(0).toJSON().Questions;

                    console.log(questions);



                }, // End Success()

                error: function(err){
                    console.log("Couldn't GET the service " + err);
                }

            }); // End Input.fetch()

            this.render();

        }, // End Initialize

        render: function(){
            el: $('#factfinder')
            var template = _.template( $("#form_template").html(), {} );
            this.$el.html(template);

        } 

    }); // End AppView.Backbone.View.extend()
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly `fetch` is Asynchronous. So you would need to always call the render when the request comes back from the server. The best way can be listening to the `reset` and `sync` event on the server and which calls the render method.

```
app.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#factfinder'),
        initialize: function() {

            var inputs = new app.Form();

            // Listen top the events that calls the success method
            this.listenTo(inputs, 'sync reset', this.renderView);
            //  to bind the this context
            _.bindAll(this, 'renderView');
            // Perform a GET on the model url to the service
            inputs.fetch({
                error: function(err){
                    console.log("Couldn't GET the service " + err);
                }
            }); // End Input.fetch()

        }, // End Initialize
        renderView: function() {
           var questions = inputs.get(0).toJSON().Questions;
           console.log(questions);
           // Call render when the request comes back with response
           this.render();
        },
        render: function(){
            var template = _.template( $("#form_template").html(), {} );
            this.$el.html(template);
        } 

    }); // End AppView.Backbone.View.extend()
```

And you have the syntax error inside the render method

```
el: $('#factfinder')
```

supposed to be

```
var el = $('#factfinder')
```

Or you can move it to outside the render

Answer (score 0):

You typically wouldn't pass the JSON to `render`, but rather set the `model`.  Also, you need to call `render` inside the `success` callback, since the fetch is asynchronous:

```
// store a reference to the view object
var self = this;

inputs.fetch({
    success: function() {
        var questions = inputs.get(0).toJSON().Questions;
        console.log(questions);
        this.model = new Backbone.Model(questions);
        self.render();
    }, // End Success()
    error: function(err){
        console.log("Couldn't GET the service " + err);
    }
}); // End Input.fetch()
```

Now in `render`, you can get the JSON back from the model:

```
this.$el.html(template(this.model.toJSON()));
```

This may seem to be a roundabout way of doing it -- construct a model from JSON, then get the JSON back from the model.  But this is by design.  It allows the model a chance to do its thing, setting any defaults it has, and validating the raw data coming back from the server.